# multi-selection list with populated data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi-selection list that needs be able to have selections from multiple sets of populated data.

We have a database of stores separated into [Company] -> [Region] -> [District] -> [Individual stores].
There are multiple stores in each district and multiple districts in each region. The companies are made out of multiple regions.

Having said that, I need to be able to select multiple stores (or possibly all stores) in specific districts (possibly from multiple districts or regions at the same time)

I figured the easiest way for this would be serial  inputs; selection of the company opens all available regions in the 2nd select box, selection of a region shows all districts in this region in the third box, and selection of of the district will show all stores in the district in the final box.

How can I allow the selection of stores from multiple districts following this setup - or do you know of a better setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by serialization also you can try the [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) plugin to select multiple with good user interface